# How to convert recorded audio to Mp3 format in Android

Tags: android, audio-converter

I am working on an app that involves Audio Recording functionality. Audio Recording is working fine but I am facing issue that I want recorded audio in mp3 format or conversion of .aac or .pcm format to mp3 format after recording.

So please if anyone have suggestion regarding this or anyone can help me out. Then please reply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of object you have the audio in?

Comment: I have following formats that are supported while recording..

THREE_GPP,  AAC_ADTS, MPEG_4, .pcm, AMR_NB, AMR_WB

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641920/how-to-encode-a-wav-to-a-mp3-on-a-android-device or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922364/recording-and-saving-audio-on-android